# Type region `ilmb_cntlr_3_dlmb_cntlr_3' overflowed by 12208 bytes o

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-edk

I'm trying to do an application using 4 microblazes:

1. microblaze_0
2. microblaze_1
3. microblaze_2
4. microblaze_3

and I connect them using FSL connection:

- microblaze_0 send data to microblaze_2 through MFSL0
- microblaze_1 send data to microblaze_2 through MFSL2
- microblaze_2 send data to microblaze_3 through MFSL4

I export design(sdk) and I created 4 projects each one contains a C program,but when I run the program corresponding the microblaze_3 I got this error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
region `ilmb_cntlr_3_dlmb_cntlr_3' overflowed by 12208 bytes    op_3                   C/C++ Problem
```

Should I add a memory wich will contain the data received from microblaze_2 then send data to microblaze_3??what type of memory should I add to it and how connect it to the microblazes?